# Как пронумеровать строки удовлетворяющие критерию в каждой группе?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, group-by

У меня есть датафрейм, в котором надо преобразовать существующие колонки. Следующее значение в колонке будет зависеть от предыдущего.

Я могу сделать эти калькуляции и преобразования с помощью списков, но хочу понять можно ли это сделать с помощью `pandas`?

Входящий датафрейм:

```
    doc    |    anno_name   | value
    -------------------------------
    doc_1  | anno_11        | 123
    doc_1  | anno_first     | 124
    doc_1  | anno_middle    | 127
    doc_1  | anno_middle    | 124
    doc_1  | anno_last      | 125
    doc_2  | anno_3334      | 124
    doc_2  | anno_middle    | 129
    doc_2  | anno_middle    | 130
    doc_2  | anno_middle    | 131
    doc_2  | anno_last      | 131
```

На выходе должно быть:

```
    doc    |    anno_name   | value
    -------------------------------
    doc_1  | anno_11        | 123
    doc_1  | anno_mult_1    | 124
    doc_1  | anno_mult_2    | 127
    doc_1  | anno_mult_3    | 124
    doc_1  | anno_mult_4    | 125
    doc_2  | anno_3334      | 124
    doc_2  | anno_mult_1    | 129
    doc_2  | anno_mult_2    | 130
    doc_2  | anno_mult_3    | 131
    doc_2  | anno_mult_4    | 131
```

Логика такая:

Если в колонке `anno_name` по одному и тому же `doc` в теле есть `first, middle, last` мне необходимо по этим значениям документа изменить название в формате `anno_mul_{n}`, где `n` - индекс. Внутри `doc` индексы начинаются с 1.

Внутри датафрейма данные могут не быть сгруппированы по одному документу (`doc`).

Главная задача, которую я хочу понять — это как мне внутри датафрейма сделать так, чтобы следующее значение в `anno_name` формировалось на основании предыдущего.

В общем, буду благодарен за советы :)

Comment: @MaxU принято, исправлено

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таких случаях обычно используют [GroupBy.cumcount()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
idx = df["anno_name"].str.contains(r"_(?:first|middle|last)")
df.loc[idx, "anno_name"] =  \
    "anno_mult_" + df.loc[idx].groupby("doc").cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

результат:

```
In [160]: df
Out[160]:
     doc    anno_name  value
0  doc_1      anno_11    123
1  doc_1  anno_mult_1    124
2  doc_1  anno_mult_2    127
3  doc_1  anno_mult_3    124
4  doc_1  anno_mult_4    125
5  doc_2    anno_3334    124
6  doc_2  anno_mult_1    129
7  doc_2  anno_mult_2    130
8  doc_2  anno_mult_3    131
9  doc_2  anno_mult_4    131
```